# Бесплатное использование Spring в IDE

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, плагин

Работаю в `IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (2023.3.3.)`.
Установлены плагины Spring & Java Tools, Spring Boot Assistant.
При попытке создать новый `Spring` проект идея предлагает обновиться до версии `Ultimate` с первым месяцем бесплатного использования, далее платно.
Подскажите, как использовать бесплатную версию Spring при создании нового объекта?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Например, сначала создать пустой maven или gradle проект, потом в нем добавить spring как зависимость, и начать проект реализовывать.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что spring проекты не имеют специфической структуры, как например maven проекты и при рекомендованном вами способе "руками" выстраивать структуру не надо будет?

Comment: Ну есть принятая структура организации классов по пакетам (контроллер, сервис, репозиторий), но в принципе по идее все достаточно гибко.

Comment: maven проекты сами по себе тоже не имеют специфической структуры (кроме необходимых файлов на верхнем уровне, типа pom файла), внутри это может быть и консольное приложение, и серверное (тот же spring), и desktop приложение. Упрощенно - maven отвечает за установку зависимостей и сборку, но не диктует прямо жестко внутреннюю структуру.

Comment: спасибо Вам большое, буду пробовать.